# Implementing TokenCache when I only need to store a single token per cache

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an app that is meant to read tenant data from multiple tenants which requires admin consent. So I just need to store one access token and one refresh token from `AquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync()` for each tenant. So I wondered, if I were to implement a TokenCache extension in such a scenario, would it be necessary to implement `TokenCache.AfterAccess` and `TokenCache.BeforeAccess`? Also, when using `AquireTokenAsync()`, are the cachebits getting overwritten by the new tokens aquired or does it just append to it? If I wanted the old tokens to be overwritten, could I simply use `TokenCache.BeforeWrite` to clear the old cache?

Basically, this is what I had in mind:

```
public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
{
    public Guid TenantId;

    public ADALTokenCache(Guid tenantId) : base()
    {
        TenantId = tenantId;
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            byte[] cache = dbContext.TokenCacheSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TenantId == TenantId);
            if (cache != null)
            {
                Deserialize(MachineKey.Unprotect(cache, "ADALCache"));
            }
        }
    }


    void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        //Could I call Clear() here so that only
        //the new token from AquireTokenAsync() is written?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To answer your questions**

- The reason why the cache in the samples is as it is, is that several users might sign-in to the application. That will, BTW be the case even if this is the same user in different tenants (the identity might be different). you have examples of implementation in 
  [Custom token cache serialization in Web applications / Web API](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Token-cache-serialization#custom-token-cache-serialization-in-web-applications--web-api)
- indeed when `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` will refresh the token it will override the previous token in the cache.

**However, stepping back**

- if I understand correctly, in your scenario, your app is not about getting a token to access data for a given user, but rather access tenant data (for the tenant where a user belongs?), and then regularly do some operations.
- Wouldn't it be more the case that you'd have a daemon application (but multi-tenant) ? and therefore you might want to use a [client credentials flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) rather than the [authorization code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps). 
  Since you are using ADAL (V1 endpoint), you could pre-consent the application in the Azure portal? you would not need to sign-in any user? The page on client credential flows has links to ADAL samples for daemon apps.
- you might also want to have a look at [active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2) which seems very close to your scenario (but for the Azure AD V2 endpoint). It's easy transposable to the Azure AD V1 endpoint, though, or you could still use the sample as is, but limit the accepted authorities to just a set of tenants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed my app is about reading tenant data rather than user data, and my first idea was to use client credentials flow, which worked well. However the idea here is that with the authorization code flow, I only need to login with an admin account once and that's enough for my app to access data from that admin's tenant, and that involves less manual steps than the credentials flow.

Comment: There are good and bad sides to both approaches. Auth code (delegated) is good because it accesses APIs in a user context, and limits access to only things that user can access. Bad side is refresh tokens can get revoked (if the password for the user is reset for example). Client credentials is good because it is reliable. The only way to revoke it is to remove the permissions manually or delete the service principal. Bad side is that it requires organization-wide access.